# How to fill ComboBox while you are typing in it?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7, vcl, autofill

I am trying to accomplish a search as you type in a `TComboBox` and add items automatically as I type.

I use Delphi 7 and MSSQL.

Lets say I have a long table with name lists in a table with one column named 'names' and I typed 'Jonathan'.

I want to get results into the `TComboBox` as I type one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at TDBLookUpComboBox?

Comment: Where did you type? in the `TComboBox`? or you type in other component and want the _ComboBox_ items to filled with data?

Comment: I type the code  on the TCombobox change event so when the user types a new query to database load the names that match to combobox. My problem is that the combobox behaves strange, add to existing items i dont need or when i clear the items and add the new items it looses focus or when i type 123 it goes to 321.

Comment: @StarDust Check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  ComboBox1.SelStart:= Length(ComboBox1.Text); //To put the cursor in the end
                                                 of the string typed in the ComboBox
  if ComboBox1.Text = '' then
    ADOTable1.Filtered:= False
      else
        begin
          ADOTable1.Filter:= 'Names LIKE ' + QuotedStr(ComboBox1.Text + '*');
          ADOTable1.Filtered:= True;
          for I := 1 to ADOTable1.RecordCount do
            begin
              ADOTable1.RecNo:= I;
              ComboBox1.Items.Add(ADOTable1.FieldByName('Names').Value);
            end;
        end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample with the TADO QUERY component? I'll try this on home and i will let you know.

Comment: @StarDust You can do the same with `TADOQuery`

Comment: Thanks, i modified a bit your logic and it works ok. However when i type quickly i have some kind of lag behavior or when i go to delete something from the middle it goes back to the end. Is there any way to have a small delay to the code after i start typing and i wait for example half second ?

Comment: @StarDust Do you mean [Sleep()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.Sleep)?